# How can I copy and rename a Java file and make the new file available during the current execution?

Tags: java

I am currently trying to create some code which requires me to rename a text file. During the same execution I must access the new file that has been created. I am using the code below:

```
public static void updateUkRepFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    CommonVariables.newFileName = "UK_REP_"+CommonMiscFunctions.getCurrentMst("MMddyyyy.hhmmss")+".txt";
    System.out.println(CommonVariables.newFileName+"NEW FILE NAME");
    File origFile = new File(fileName);
    File destFile = new File("src/test/resources/testDataFiles/"+CommonVariables.newFileName);
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try{
        is = new FileInputStream(origFile);
        os = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = is.read(buffer)) >0 ){
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }finally{
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work for me because the new file isn't available until the END of the execution so I get an error. How can I rename and copy the file AND make it available instantly to use throughout my program?

Comment: I don't understand why it wouldn't be available but anyway why are you not using one of the copy methods in `Files`?

Comment: I ended up doing exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Files.copy method to meet my requirements`

```
public static void updateUkRepFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File fileToUpload = new File(String.valueOf(fileName));

        System.out.println("original file to upload "+ fileToUpload);

        String tdFileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        String fileExtn = tdFileName.substring(tdFileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
        long ut1 = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
        String newFileName = tdFileName.substring(0,tdFileName.lastIndexOf("."))+ut1+"_UK_REP"+"."+fileExtn;
        String dirName = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/testDataFiles/UKRep/";
        Files.copy(Paths.get(fileName), Paths.get(dirName, newFileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        CommonVariables.newFileName=newFileName;
        System.out.println("NEW FILE NAME: "+newFileName);
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the destination file using the method `createNewFile()` present in `java.io.File` class

Update the code to this :

```
public static void updateUkRepFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    CommonVariables.newFileName = "UK_REP_"+CommonMiscFunctions.getCurrentMst("MMddyyyy.hhmmss")+".txt";
    System.out.println(CommonVariables.newFileName+"NEW FILE NAME");
    File origFile = new File(fileName);
    File destFile = new File("src/test/resources/testDataFiles/"+CommonVariables.newFileName);
    destFile.createNewFile(); // this creates the file in the location.
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try{
        is = new FileInputStream(origFile);
        os = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = is.read(buffer)) >0 ){
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }finally{
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a thread sleep to pause the execution of the current thread after renaming the file and add InterruptedException to updateUkRepFile method signature

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```